# regex - return all before the second occurrence

Tags: regex, r

Given this string:

```
DNS000001320_309.0/121.0_t0
```

How would I return everything before the second occurrence of "_"?

```
DNS000001320_309.0/121.0
```

I am using R.

Thanks.

Comment: Any guarantee that the strings will always have a second _?  How do you want to handle cases where there are 0 or 1 underscores?

Comment: It will always have 2 "_"s... guaranteed! The string is a `paste` of 3 strings using `sep="_"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think this might do the task (regex to match everything befor the last occurence of `_`):

```
_([^_]*)$
```

E.g.:

```
> sub('_([^_]*)$', '', "DNS000001320_309.0/121.0_t0")
[1] "DNS000001320_309.0/121.0"
```

Comment: Yeah, if the regex-path is walked, `sub` would be more appropriate than `gsub`.

Comment: If there are more than two underscores this will select beyond the second underscore, although apparently that doesn't matter to the OP, so I point it out only for posterity.

Comment: Yeah, good point @joran. It may matter to the OP, but he might not be aware of it.

Answer (score 54):

The following script:

```
s <- "DNS000001320_309.0/121.0_t0"
t <- gsub("^([^_]*_[^_]*)_.*$", "\\1", s)
t
```

will print:

```
DNS000001320_309.0/121.0
```

A quick explanation of the regex:

```
^         # the start of the input
(         # start group 1
  [^_]*   #   zero or more chars other than `_`
  _       #   a literal `_`
  [^_]*   #   zero or more chars other than `_`
)         # end group 1
_         # a literal `_`
.*        # consume the rest of the string
$         # the end of the input
```

which is replaced with:

```
\\1       # whatever is matched in group 1
```

And if there are less than 2 underscores, the string is not changed.

Comment: Wow, really nice, detailed answer (+1). I definitely like your solution better than mine :)

Comment: What if there are more than 2 underscores?? Is there a way to further generalize this function?

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I hate regex, so luckily there's a way to do this without them, just by splitting the string:

```
> s <- "DNS000001320_309.0/121.0_t0"      
> paste(strsplit(s,"_")[[1]][1:2],collapse = "_")
[1] "DNS000001320_309.0/121.0"
```

Although of course this assumes that there will always be at least 2 underscores in your string, so be careful if you vectorize this and that isn't the case.

Comment: This is very useful.  Can you explain what the first double-bracketed index/number (i.e., [[1]]) is doing?

Comment: @KDA strsplit() is vectorized so it returns a list of vectors that have been split. If you just have one element you still have to pluck the first element.

Answer (score 7):

not pretty but this will do the trick

```
mystr <- "DNS000001320_309.0/121.0_t0"

mytok <- paste(strsplit(mystr,"_")[[1]][1:2],collapse="_")
```