# How can I iterate a function over specific columns of a series of dataframes where I can set the order?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

I work for an insurance company and I am trying to improve something that I built. I have about **150 data frames** that look like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt_Premium<-data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
               Base_Premium_Fire= c(45,55,105,92),
               Base_Premium_Water= c(20,21,24,29),
               Base_Premium_Theft= c(3,5,6,7))

dt_Discount_Factors<-data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
               Discount_Factor_Fire= c(.9,.95,.99,.97),
               Discount_Factor_Water= c(.8,.85,.9,.96),
               Discount_Factor_Theft= c(1,1,1,1))

dt_Territory_Factors<-data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
               Territory_Factor_Fire= c(1.9,1.2,.91,1.03),
               Territory_Factor_Water= c(1.03,1.3,1.25,1.01),
               Territory_Factor_Theft= c(1,1.5,1,.5))

dt_Fixed_Expense<-data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
               Fixed_Expense_Fire= c(5,5,5,5),
               Fixed_Expense_Water= c(7,7,7,7),
               Fixed_Expense_Theft= c(9,9,9,9))
```

I take the base premium and then I multiply by factors, and then add a fixed expense at the very end. My code is currently something like:

```
dt_Final_Premium<-cbind(dt_Premium[,1],dt_Premium[,2:4]*
                          dt_Discount_Factors[,2:4]*
                          dt_Territory_Factors[,2:4]+
                          dt_Fixed_Expense[,2:4])
```

What I hate about this:

-The 2:4 stuff (I would like to be able to use a named range)

-The typing is monstrous considering all of the tables and policies I actually have

-It is very confusing for anybody except me (the author) to understand and edit/adjust the code

-I would like to be able to have each rating step as part of a list, and then just iterate over that list (or a similar process).

-Ideally I would be able to get the values at each step. For example :

```
step2_answer<-cbind(dt_Premium[,1],dt_Premium[,2:4]*
                      dt_Discount_Factors[,2:4])
```

There just has to be a way were I can take a dataframe/datatable and then just multiply or add to the next dataframe/datatable in the series. Thanks for taking a look at this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your columns have a clean naming, some pivoting may do the work:

```
library(tidyverse) #to be run after library(data.table)
dt_Premium %>%
  left_join(dt_Discount_Factors, by="Policy") %>%
  left_join(dt_Territory_Factors, by="Policy") %>%
  left_join(dt_Fixed_Expense, by="Policy") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=-Policy)%>% 
  separate(name, into=c("name", "object"), sep="_.*_") %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  mutate(total=Base*Discount*Territory+Fixed) %>% #or calculate the value for a specific step
  select(Policy, object, total) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "object", values_from = "total")
```

After joining all the columns, you can pivot to a long format and turn columns to rows. There, you can separate the name into the real name (Base, Discount, Fixed...) and the object (Fire, Water, ...) and return to the wide format. The tricky part is to get a good regular expression, as your names use the underscore twice. Mine can be vastly improved but will do the work for now.

After this, you can calculate whatever you want, select only the result and pivot to wide one last time. If you want to get all the results, you may tweak this last pivot with prefixes.

Pivoting is quite a gymnastics, but it has proven to be very effective once you get used to it.

As you have a lot of tables, if you can get them as a list, you can also use `purrr::reduce` to join them all at once and simplify the first lines of code:

```
list(dt_Premium, dt_Discount_Factors, dt_Territory_Factors, dt_Fixed_Expense) %>% 
  reduce(left_join, by='Policy') %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=-Policy)%>% 
  separate(name, into=c("name", "object"), sep="_.*_") %>% 
  pivot_wider() %>% 
  mutate(total=Base*Discount*Territory+Fixed) %>% #of calculate the value for a specific step
  select(Policy, object, total) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "object", values_from = "total")
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this using dplyr?!
Here I am using the same calculation that you have mentioned but row wise using mutate function of dplyr which makes it clear to see the step by step and for anyone to understand the calculation easily.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

dt_Premium <- data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
                         Base_Premium_Fire= c(45,55,105,92),
                         Base_Premium_Water= c(20,21,24,29),
                         Base_Premium_Theft= c(3,5,6,7))

dt_Discount_Factors <- data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
                                  Discount_Factor_Fire= c(.9,.95,.99,.97),
                                  Discount_Factor_Water= c(.8,.85,.9,.96),
                                  Discount_Factor_Theft= c(1,1,1,1))

dt_Territory_Factors <- data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
                                   Territory_Factor_Fire= c(1.9,1.2,.91,1.03),
                                   Territory_Factor_Water= c(1.03,1.3,1.25,1.01),
                                   Territory_Factor_Theft= c(1,1.5,1,.5))

dt_Fixed_Expense <- data.table(Policy = c("Pol123","Pol333","Pol555","Pol999"),
                               Fixed_Expense_Fire= c(5,5,5,5),
                               Fixed_Expense_Water= c(7,7,7,7),
                               Fixed_Expense_Theft= c(9,9,9,9))

dt_Final_Premium <- cbind(dt_Premium[,1],dt_Premium[,2:4]*
                            dt_Discount_Factors[,2:4]*
                            dt_Territory_Factors[,2:4]+
                            dt_Fixed_Expense[,2:4])

new_dt_final_premium <-
  dt_Premium %>%
  # Joining all tables together
  left_join(dt_Discount_Factors, by = "Policy") %>%
  left_join(dt_Territory_Factors, by = "Policy") %>%
  left_join(dt_Fixed_Expense, by = "Policy") %>%

  # Calculating required calculation
  mutate(
    Base_Premium_Fire = 
      Base_Premium_Fire * Discount_Factor_Fire * Territory_Factor_Fire + Fixed_Expense_Fire,
    Base_Premium_Water = 
      Base_Premium_Water * Discount_Factor_Water * Territory_Factor_Water + Fixed_Expense_Water,
    Base_Premium_Theft = 
      Base_Premium_Theft * Discount_Factor_Theft * Territory_Factor_Theft + Fixed_Expense_Theft) %>%
  select(Policy, Base_Premium_Fire, Base_Premium_Water, Base_Premium_Theft)
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. It is actually pretty similar to what I have currently, but your code is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to reorganize the data by converting into a long format, merge and then perform the calculations:

```
DT <- Reduce(merge, lapply(dtList, function(d) {
    vn <- sub('_([^_]*)$', '', names(d)[2L]) #see reference [1]
    melt(d, id.vars="Policy", value.name=vn)[,
        variable := gsub("(.*)_(.*)_(.*)", "\\3", variable)]
}))
DT

DT[, disc_prem := Base_Premium * Discount_Factor][,
    disc_prem_loc := disc_prem * Territory_Factor][,
        Final_Premium := disc_prem_loc + Fixed_Expense]
```

output:

```
    Policy variable Base_Premium Discount_Factor Territory_Factor Fixed_Expense disc_prem disc_prem_loc Final_Premium
 1: Pol123     Fire           45            0.90             1.90             5     40.50       76.9500       81.9500
 2: Pol123    Theft            3            1.00             1.00             9      3.00        3.0000       12.0000
 3: Pol123    Water           20            0.80             1.03             7     16.00       16.4800       23.4800
 4: Pol333     Fire           55            0.95             1.20             5     52.25       62.7000       67.7000
 5: Pol333    Theft            5            1.00             1.50             9      5.00        7.5000       16.5000
 6: Pol333    Water           21            0.85             1.30             7     17.85       23.2050       30.2050
 7: Pol555     Fire          105            0.99             0.91             5    103.95       94.5945       99.5945
 8: Pol555    Theft            6            1.00             1.00             9      6.00        6.0000       15.0000
 9: Pol555    Water           24            0.90             1.25             7     21.60       27.0000       34.0000
10: Pol999     Fire           92            0.97             1.03             5     89.24       91.9172       96.9172
11: Pol999    Theft            7            1.00             0.50             9      7.00        3.5000       12.5000
12: Pol999    Water           29            0.96             1.01             7     27.84       28.1184       35.1184
```

data:

```
dtLs <- list(dt_Premium, dt_Discount_Factors, dt_Territory_Factors, dt_Fixed_Expense)
```

Reference:

1. [regex-return-all-before-the-second-occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7449564/regex-return-all-before-the-second-occurrence/7449766#7449766)

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing reading some of rdata.table vignettes would help you tighten up syntax and make it more terse. Some of us think terse = 'more readable' in numeric programming. Others think that represents some level of insanity:

```
vignette(package="data.table")
```

Understanding Map, Reduce, mget and other functional notation in R and rdata.table may help. Here are some things I have done from a data.table mindset:

Dropping cols syntax might be more terse using 'i' to drop a vector of cols:

```
dt[is.na(dt)] <- 0  # replace NA with 0
drop_col_list <- c('dropcol1','dropcol2','dropcol3') # drop col list
# dt <- dt[!drop_col_list,sapply(dt,as.numeric)] # make selected dt cols numeric type
dt[!drop_col_list,SumCol := Reduce(`+`, dt)]  # adds Sum col with 'functional programming' iteration
```

The lapply(.SD, func) format is very powerful:

```
fsum <- function(x) {sum(x,na.rm=TRUE)}
dt[,lapply(.SD,fsum),by=,.SDcols=c("col1","col2","col3","col4")]
# or
dt[!drop_col_list,lapply(.SD,fsum)]
```

This shows applying the internal data.table 'set' function (':=') and mget to create cols derived from operations with functional programming on two data.tables. The data.table(s) may need to have the same nrow():

```
nm1 <- names(dt1)[1:4]
nm2 <- names(dt2)[1:4]
dt[, SumCol := Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`, mget(nm1), mget(nm2)))]
```

The loop below isn't really rdata.table'esq' programming but outputs a data.table. Probably this isn't as fast as more data.table like syntax:

```
seqXpi <- function(x) {x * pi}
seqXexp <- function(x) {x * exp(1)}
l <- {};
for(x in seq(1,10,1)) l <- as.data.table(rbind(l,cbind(seq=x,seqXpi=seqXpi(x),seqXexp=seqXexp(x))))
```